# The logic for awarding tag badges

Tags: discussion, tag-badges

I noticed that [Mysticial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/) is yet to be awarded the silver tag badge for the tag [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/performance/info) despite being responsible for [the legendary answer on performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902).

Here's an image of what I see of their reputation tab.

[image: Mysticial's reputation tab]

I find that rather absurd. They should be awarded the performance tag based on that one answer alone.

I think the logic for awarding tag badge need to be re-thought. A weighting mechanism should be used in addition to the current criteria that you need to meet both the score requirement AND the answer requirement.

If current criteria are met, award the badge.

Else, use a weighting mechanism.

One example:

If a badge requires 400 scores, give each score 1/400 value.
If a badge requires 80 answers, give each answer 1/80 valule.

If `(score * (1/400) + answer * (1/80))` exceed some threshold greater than 2, then award the badge.

[Mysticial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/) would be awarded the badge even if the threshold were 68. I suggest using a lesser threshold, say 20.

Comment: Nothing is more absurd than the sheer number of popularity votes on that answer and the question. There is honestly nothing about that answer that differentiates it from other answers of its kind that have only a hundredth of its sheer score (and that's like, 200 upvotes). Mysticial himself would agree. Its astronomical score is but a meme and a fluke at this point, much like bobince's regex answer.

Comment: The thresholds exist to prevent *exactly what you are suggesting* from happening. Users shouldn't be getting tag badges for participating only a few times and getting insanely high scores on those posts.

Comment: Why do we even have a `performance` tag anyway? Seems kinda meta-tag-ish...

Comment: While that example is a stellar answer, you shouldn't get a tag badge based on one post alone. Many examples that you can find with thousands of upvotes are answers to trivial questions that a lot of people happen to have. You already get a badge for high upvotes on a single answer. There's no reason to water down tag badges by showering them around.

Comment: He **does** have that badge, the bronze flavor.  He only needs to post 5 more answers to get the silver one.  He only posted 2 answers last year so that's going to take between forever and never.  Not like there's much point to still post, he hits the rep cap almost every day.

Comment: @HansPassant I haven't posted anything in the past couple years because of two things: 1) I have a full-time job now. So I don't have as much time as before. My current workplace forbids copy-pasting anything from the internet. So it makes it impossible for me to run any SSCCEs that the OP provides while I'm at work. 2) It's become exponentially harder to find anything worth answering - let alone while I'm at home during off-hours where I'm properly equipped to answer the performance stuff that I like to answer.

Answer (score 20):

The required number of answers is there for a reason, specifically the one you want it removed for. Writing one *good* answer does not mean you know a lot about the subject. Weighting the requirements would mean that someone could get the badge for several poor or mediocre answers and a couple of extremely popular (or on occasion stellar) ones.

Tag badges are meant to give a sort of badge of expertise. If you can gain the required score, either you're good at writing popular answers or you're good at writing great answers. You could be doing both, of course. If you can write the required number of answers *and* maintain the required score, you likely have a good deal of knowledge on the subject*, considering the fact that writing answers that become downvoted will lower your score.

Keep in mind that gold tag badges come with an extra ability: [Mjolnir or the Dupe Hammer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212) Currently, silver and bronze badges do not come with extra moderation tools, but [they could in the future.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240700/empowering-tag-badge-holders-part-ii-lets-look-at-silver) Do we really want to make these abilities easier to obtain for people who may not have the knowledge to use them effectively, or people who managed to hit the Stack Overflow lottery?

<sub>* Or you got lucky and found a lot of easy, popular, on-topic questions to answer quickly. That *could* happen, but it still takes more work than one or two popular answers.</sub>

Comment: "If you can write the required number of answers and maintain the required score" Keep in mind that the criteria for all three tiers of tag badges (bronze, silver and gold), when met exactly, will leave you with a ratio of a score of 5 per answer. Want a real challenge? Earn a gold tag badge with a score-per-answer ratio of 5 or greater in that tag, with as few deleted answers as you can manage, and as few outliers as possible. Or just maintain this ratio for as long as possible while continuing to contribute actively.

Comment: @BoltClock I have enough of a challenge finding a good question _to_ answer, let alone writing a good answer. Anyone who can keep a ratio like that up is worthy of more than a badge in my opinion.